# ROS package that contains python package with a subpackage is not installed properly

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS package that contains a python package with a subpackage (nested python package). When I build the ROS package and source `devel` workspace, I can import the subpackage as expected. However if I source `install` workspace I cannot import subpackge anymore, only module of the outer python package (`a.py`).

Here is example file structure:

```
my_ws/src/ros_pkg/
    CMakeLists.txt
    package.xml
    setup.py
    src/
        my_pkg/
            __init__.py
            a.py
            my_subpkg/
                __init__.py
                b.py
```

Content of the `setup.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=[
        'my_pkg',
    ],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

Setup basic ROS package containing python package as provided in example file structure Then build it.

```
catkin config --install
catkin build my_pkg
```

Source devel workspace and try to import nested module in python (it works).

```
source devel/setup.bash
python -c 'from my_pkg import a'  # Works
```

Now source install workplace (in fresh shell) and try to import it again. It fails.

```
source devel/setup.bash
python -c 'from my_pkg import a'  # Works
python -c 'from my_pkg.my_subpkg import b'  # Fails (ImportError: No module named my_subpkg)
```

As suspected, there is no python subpackage in the install workspace (`my_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages /my_pkg/`)

```
my_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_pkg/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    # my_subpkg/ is not here
```

I tested it on python 2 and 3 (ROS melodic and noetic).

Can anyone tell me how to achieve that the subpackage would be accessible when the `install` workspace is sourced?

**Full story:**
I normally source `devel` workspace when working with ROS, however, I also use Industrial CI (https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci) where tests are run based on `install` workspace (if I am not mistaken), which consequentially fails in that case. So if `catkin` cannot be configured to avoid this issue, maybe Industrial CI can be tweaked to pass tests?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404497/ros-package-that-contains-python-package-with-a-subpackage-is-not-installed-properly/) by [BlazP](https://answers.ros.org/users/112415/blazp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-08**:
Following references may be helpful.

1. https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/316
2. https://answers.ros.org/question/367793/including-a-python-module-in-a-ros2-package/
3. https://roboticsbackend.com/ros-import-python-module-from-another-package/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a problem with catkin or CI, you just have to fix your setup.py.

From https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages:

> Keep in mind that although package_dir applies recursively, you must explicitly list all packages in packages: the Distutils will not recursively scan your source tree looking for any directory with an _*init*_.py file

catkin does not offer any special support here (http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html):

> Note: As in setuptools, the packages list is not recursive, and sub-packages must be included explicitly (e.g. your_package.tools.my_util which would contain the python modules defined in the folder src/your_package/tools/my_util/, along with an _*init*_.py file)

If you want `my_pkg.my_subpkg` to get installed, you have to list it explicitly.

```
packages=[
  'my_pkg',
  'my_pkg.my_subpkg', 
],
```

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2022-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlazP](https://answers.ros.org/users/112415/blazp/) on 2022-08-09**:
Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.